# How to make a table view fill entire view pragmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to make a UITable View fill the entire view with the options I supply. As of now I have four options. This is the code I am running:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            return (screensize.height-70)/4 //Whatever fits your need for that cell
        } else {
            return (screensize.height-70)/4 // other cell height
        }
}
```

The 70 comes from the navigation bar I have at the top of my page which takes 70 pixels. My problem is that no matter what I get some sort of white space buffer at the bottom of the simulator. Even with hard coded values I don't seem to be able to fill the display. It will display the first 3 options and then you'll have to scroll for the fourth. Please help.

UPDATE: To set the table dimensions I used:

tableView.frame        =   CGRectMake(0, 71, screenSize.height-70, screenSize.width);

Comment: You've shown us how you're sizing your table view rows, but you haven't shown us how you make the table view itself fill the screen.

Comment: @robmayoff I used 
tableView.frame         =   CGRectMake(0, 71, screenSize.height-70, screenSize.width);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these to get your `screen` width and `height`

```
let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
```

And then use these values fill your view with the `scrollView` or any other `view` if you need.